# Specific website returns blank page

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Recently, I've tried to access a specific website (other websites work) but I get a blank page on my computer. 
I'm sure the problem is my computer because I tried on the same network with my smartphone (w/ google chrome) and it works. Also tried to change the browser on my computer (safari, google chrome, firefox), restarting the computer, and also restarting the wifi router. I also tried to clear cache on the google chrome browser and switching off the adblocker.

I have no idea why it still does not work, any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an HTTPS address? If you open DevTools (F12 in Chrome), switch to the Network tab, and hit F5 to reload the page, does it literally say "content-length: 0" in the response? In the Security tab, does the HTTPS certificate look as expected, or is it issued by Some Antivirus Software CA?

Comment: It is a https adress, no "content-length: 0" in the response, and looks normal in security tab. Using the non-https address doesn't resolve the problem.